# Подключить кастомный шрифт ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь поключить кастомный шрифт на странице через файл `_Layout.cshtml`.

Собственно вот код:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<style type="text/css">
    @@font-face {
        font-family: "San Francisco";
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url("https://applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-regular-webfont.woff");
    }

    .Text {
        font-family: "San Francisco";
    }
</style>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Но проблема в том что шрифт как был `Helvetica`, так и остался. В dev console нет ошибок вообще

В чем ошибка, как правильно подключить шрифт?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Возможно у тебя где-то в "~/Content/css" задается шрифт Helvetica который заменяет твой, попробуй указать кастомный шрифт после загрузки основных стилей. Вот еще хороший ответ по шрифтам http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812441/how-do-i-use-woff-fonts-for-my-website

Comment: хм. возможно в стилях бутстрапа, окей, спасибо попробую @AlexanderKondratenko

Comment: Да, так и есть, спасибо! @AlexanderKondratenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя где-то в "~/Content/css" задается шрифт Helvetica который заменяет твой кастомный, попробуй указать его после загрузки основных стилей:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: "San Francisco";
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url("https://applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-regular-webfont.woff");
    }

    .Text {
        font-family: "San Francisco";
    }
</style>
```

**Перес комментарий**